# Alguém sabe resolver esse problema: cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Já removi o ruby e tudo mais e atualizei o sistema, mas isso passou a acontecer depois da atualização do Jekyll

:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

Não consigo rodar nenhum comando relacionado.

Comment: cade o código pra analisar onde pode estar o erro?

Comment: Olha este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror tem um bom número de respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja usando RVM tente:

```
rvm fix-permissions    
rvm reinstall VERSÃO_DO_SEU_RUBY
```

Caso não tente:

```
gem install rubygems-update    
update_rubygems
```